# Scrolling UITableView if quantity of cells are less than one screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have `UITableView` with `UITextfield` in every cell. At start of this scene I have one cell in tableView, when I am start to typing - quantity of cells become increase:[image]

If in this position I will add one more cell, it will be overlapped by keyboard, so I need to scroll tableView to keep current textField in focus. I tried `-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`but looks like it works only if cells quantity is more than can fit at one screen (not sure if it is tableView contentInset < cells count * cell height), so it not worked. I think also of doing animation at tableView frame, but this seems to be clunky decision.
So, how can I scroll this tableView with just few cells?

Answer (score 1):

An Option is to resize the tableView frame when edit begins.  See example below. (table view is instantiated programatically, including the cell register.  With the resized tableView, the scroll should work.     I hope it helps... e

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>
@property UITableView *myTableView;
@property NSArray *array;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myTableView, array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 300);
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
    [myTableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.textField.delegate = self;
    array = @[@"one", @"two"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.title.text = array[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return array.count;
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @enharo2! And increasing cells set tableView frame to original step by step?

Comment: You only need to intercept the textFieldShouldReturn method and modify the tableView.frame accordingly, so it can resize to full screen.    `- (void) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {myTableView.frame = self.view.frame}`